# Get-PnPFile file hash convert cannot convert the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File" value of type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File" to type

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive

Any ideas how to get the file hash of a OneDrive (SP) file? I really can't stand SP would be nice to do with PnP

```
$res = (Get-PnPFile -URL "/Documents/Au-Crouchy.xlsx").OpenBinaryStream()
Invoke-PnPQuery
$stream = Add-PnpFile -FileName $a  -Folder "TargetLib" -Stream $res.Value
Get-FileHash -InputStream $stream | select-object hash
```

I tried other options for getting the file hash. Error received is:

Get-FileHash : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'InputStream'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File" value of type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File" to type "System.IO.Stream".

Thanks